# Opening cmd using psexec to a specific remote directory

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, psexec

The goal is to delete the temporary internet files on a remote computer.

```
start psexec -u domain\username  -p password  -s \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
cmd cd C:\Documents and Settings\USERACCOUNT\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files
```

Which is connecting to the remote computer but just opening to `c:windows\system`. I am then able to `cd` to that directory and use `del /f /s /q *.*` to delete all the problem files.

I tried using `psexec \\computer cmd /c del fileName` but had even less luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work using

```
psexec -u domain\user  -p password \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -s cmd /c rd "C:\Documents and Settings\%USERACCOUNT%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\" /s /q
```

which connects to the remote server, goes straight to the directory I want and proceeds to delete the particular temp internet files folder that's causing issues without bothering me at all.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother cd'ing to directory first? This should work:

```
psexec \\1.2.3.4 -u "domain\username" -p "password" cmd /c del /f /s /q "C:\Document and Settings\USERACCOUNT\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is okay but missing the server name

```
psexec \\\servername -u ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to create a directory in remote location.

`psexec \\\IPAddress -u username -p Password cmd /c mkdir c:\testfolder`